# swap on zram is not being used in Linux-3.12

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, swap

We are using BBB based custom board, It has 4GB of eMMc and 256MB of RAM,

We are seeing fragmentation issue so I thought of enabling `ZRAM` and mounting swap on it.

I enabled following configuration in kernel menuconfig

```
CONFIG_ZSMALLOC=y
CONFIG_ZRAM=y
```

and then I am running following from init script,

```
echo 256M > /sys/block/zram0/disksize
mkswap /dev/zram0
```

added following entry in `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/zram0 none swap sw,pri=32767 0 0
```

On reboot I see from free command swap is enabled from ``

```
# free
             total         used         free       shared      buffers
Mem:        251432       244668         6764            0        19592
-/+ buffers:             225076        26356
Swap:       262140            0       262140
```

I am performing memory intensive operation(big tar extraction) still
`swap` is never used I always see its value `0` :(

am I missing something ?

Any suggestions/pointers ?

Comment: Can someone throw some light on this one? please..

Answer (score 1):

Only anonymous/heap pages are swapped out. A big tar operation may not create enough heap allocation to trigger swapping. This kind of workload would simple fill up lot of pagecache pages which does not go to swap.

Comment: Thank you for reply ngupta. Right that's what is happening, that big tar is filling up pagecache and all high order blocks are used and then we see page allocation error while tar extraction. If we keep dropping caches using `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` and `echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/compact_memory` (in infinite while in background) then we don't see any error. I thought pages will be swapped out to `ZRAM` based swap and that might solve the problem.

Comment: Pagecache pages are not swapped out to any swapped device. When system is under memory pressure, clean pagecache pages are simply freed and dirty pagecache pages are written out to the filesystem. Only anonymous (heap) pages are swapped out, so these are the only type of pages that zram would receive (unless you create a filesystem on zram itself).

Comment: Thank you for reply, right only problem we have is kernel is not freeing clean pagecache pages when there is a memory pressure. If we explicitly ask (by `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_cahces` then kernel is freeing clean pagecache pages. I don't know how to make kernel to do it regularly and more frequently atleast in memory pressure situation. Do u have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing swapon
For details you can check man
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/swapon.8.html

Comment: Thank you for reply Alex, I have a init script which does `swapon -a` That's how I see swap enabled in `free` command.

Comment: Can you check cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness ? For your interest http://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness

Comment: `/proc/sys/vm/swappiness` is set to 60.